# How do you make a working clock with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, clock

Here's my broken spaghetti JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = new Date;
    var hours = Date.getHours();
    var mins = Date.getMinutes();
    if(hours > 12){
        var hour = (hours - 12);
        var ampm = "PM";
    }
    else{
        var hour = hours;
        var ampm = "AM";
    }
    var time = hour + ":" + mins, ampm
    $("h1").html(time);
    });
});
```

Can you help me make a working clock?

Comment: Please create a reasonable title/subject.

Comment: You're code is only going to run one time ... what are you intending to do?

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I gave you an upvote just for the title.

Comment: upvote means *"This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear."* And at least 5 people on StackOverflow think this question meets that criteria.

Answer (score 3):

Fixes noted in comments:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = new Date;
    var hours = d.getHours(); // call methods on your instance d
    var mins = d.getMinutes();
    if (hours > 12) {
        var hour = (hours - 12);
        var ampm = "PM";
    }
    else {
        var hour = hours;
        var ampm = "AM";
    }
    var time = hour + ":" + mins + ampm; // string concatenate ampm
    $("h1").html(time);
});​ // removed extraneous });
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/CHmbd/)

This will display the current time *once* in every `h1` tag. Look at [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) to learn about having it update periodically.

Comment: `new Date` with no parens is legal.

Comment: The first one isn't really a fix. `new Date` will still call the constructor.

Comment: @GGG: And I was just about to delete mine, but now I can't. ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all your JS code looks buggy. I assume you wanted to have something like

```
var d = new Date();
var hours = d.getHours();
var mins = d.getMinutes();
...
var time = hour + ":" + mins + ", " + ampm;
```

and for a clock you need an interval... the current code only produces the current time stamp

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be closing your call to `ready` twice.

```
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will create a clock that updates every second after the DOM is ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    updateTime();
    clock = window.setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
});
function updateTime() {
    var d = new Date;
    var hours = d.getHours();
    var mins = d.getMinutes();
    var secs = d.getSeconds();
    if(hours > 12){
        var hour = (hours - 12);
        var ampm = "PM";
    }
    else{
        var hour = hours;
        var ampm = "AM";
    } 
    var time = hour + " : " + mins + ' ; ' + secs + ' ' + ampm;
    $("h1").html(time);
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct

```
var d = new Date();
var hours = d.getHours();
var mins = d.getMinutes();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Time will be updated**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getTime()
    {
        var d = new Date;
        var hours = d.getHours();
        var mins = d.getMinutes();
       if(hours > 12)
       {
           var hour = (hours - 12);
           var ampm = "PM";
       }
       else
       {
           var hour = hours;
           var ampm = "AM";
       }
       return hour + ":" + mins+ampm;
    }

    setInterval(function(){ // Time will be updated
        $("h1").html(getTime())
    }, 500);

});
```

[**An example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/uekQa/)